# $(selector).each() function not working

Tags: jquery

I am using the following function in my jquery code

```
$('#columns').each(function (index) {
alert('here');
});
```

I am pretty much sure that I have a div with Id columns in my aspx code, but the issue is that this loop is not getting executed while running the code. 
not only this.. I have a few other .each loops in my code but none of them are working.
any help with this?

even if I use

```
$('p').each(function (index) { ....
```

or

```
$('div').each(function (index) { ....
```

or

```
$('.column').each(function (index) { ....
```

still it wont work.

UPDATE: 
Following is the structure of my jquery

```
var iWidget = {

    jQuery: $,

    settings: {....},
...Code goes here
init: function () {

        this.func1();
        this.func2();
    },....
}
.
iWidget.init();
```

Comment: ID values must be unique, so that loop will never work (there will only ever be one element). If none of your attempts work, make sure you are running your code after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Looks like the dom is not loaded when your code is executed.

Comment: please post your html code of the "#colums" div. so that we can help you debug it. PS: if you use masterpages in asp.net 3.5, the Id may very likely not be "colums" but be "ct100_content_....colums" like this. and, suggest you to use firefox to debug. just shift+F4 can run js.

Comment: Is `jQuery` loaded/included? Posting your `html` would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not using this with IDs only.. ID i just added to debug my code.. but it did not.. I am using the classes to identify actually..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function should have two parameters:

```
function(index,next)
```

Comment: This won't make any difference. You don't have to assign each argument to an identifier.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are adding '**each**' method on the id element. Not on class element.